# How do I access the children in my firebase database and display them in the activity according to the listview item selected

Tags: android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I have my app whwere i need to display the information regarding the item that is clicked on in the listview. However that is the data stored in my firebase database. The database looks like this:

[image: Database]

Now i want to click on the listview item so that i can display the information corresponding to it in a different activity.

The code for the MainActivity where the listview and Firebase is stored is:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


DrawerLayout drawer;
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
private ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;
private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;
public TicketAdapter adapter;
private final static  int RC_SIGN_IN = 2;
public String mUsername;
public static String ComplaintID;
public static String StatusImg;
public static String TicketCat;
public static String SubCat;
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Ticket");

    mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                onSignedInInitialized(user.getDisplayName());
            } else {
                onSignedOutCleanup();
                startActivityForResult(
                        getInstance()
                                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                                .setAvailableProviders(Arrays.asList(
                                        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
                                        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()))
                                .build(),
                        RC_SIGN_IN);
            }
        }
    };

    final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvTicket);
    final ArrayList<Ticket> arrayOfTicket = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new TicketAdapter(this, arrayOfTicket);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    mDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            Ticket ticket = (Ticket)dataSnapshot.getValue(Ticket.class);
            adapter.add(ticket);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            assert ticket != null;

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    final DatabaseReference TicketCategory = mDatabaseReference.child("Ticket").child("ticketCategory");

    TicketCategory.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String TCategory = dataSnapshot.child("ticketCategory").getValue(String.class);
            TicketCat = TCategory;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Ticket ticket = new Ticket();

            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ComplaintDetail.class);

            startActivity(intent);
        }


    });

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.complaintbutton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                  public void onClick(View view) {
                                      Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TicketCategory.class);
                                      startActivity(intent);
                                  }
                              }
    );

}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    toggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.action_settings:
        {
            AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(this);
            return true;
        }
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void detachDatabaseReadListener()
{
    if(mChildEventListener != null)
    {
        mDatabaseReference.removeEventListener(mChildEventListener);
        mChildEventListener = null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    mFirebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
}

private void onSignedInInitialized(String username)
{
    mUsername = username;
   // attachDatabaseReadListener();
}

private void onSignedOutCleanup()
{
    mUsername = null;

}
```

This is the code for the activity where i want to display the children:

```
 public class ComplaintDetail extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_complaint_detail);

    TextView tvComplaintID = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.complaintid);
    TextView tvTicketCat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TicketHeading);
    TextView tvSubCat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Subheading);

    //tvComplaintID.setText(MainActivity.StatusImg);
     tvTicketCat.setText( MainActivity.TicketCat);
  // tvSubCat.setText(MainActivity.SubCat);


    final Button butt = findViewById(R.id.review);
    butt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ComplaintDetail.this, Review.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    final Button button = findViewById(R.id.close);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(ComplaintDetail.this, "This ticket is closed!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}}
```

I want to display the children: **ticketCategory, subcategory and status**.
I will highly appreciate any help.
thank you!!

[**EDIT**]

```
 public class Ticket {
String ticketCategory;
String name;
String complaintID;
String subcategory;
String priority;
String status;
private String comments;
private String cannedReply;

public Ticket(){}


public Ticket (String ticketCategory, String subcategory, String priority, String status, String comments, String cannedReply)
{
    this.ticketCategory = ticketCategory;
 //   this.Name = Name;
    this.subcategory = subcategory;
    this.priority = priority;
    this.status = status;
    this.comments = comments;
    this.cannedReply = cannedReply;
}

public void setTicketCategory(String ticketCategory) {
    this.TicketCategory = ticketCategory;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.Name = name;
}

public void setSubcategory(String subcategory) {
    this.Subcategory = subcategory;
}

public void setPriority(String priority) {
    this.priority = priority;
}*/

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getTicketCategory() {
    return ticketCategory;
}



public String getSubcategory() {
    return subcategory;
}

public String getPriority() {
    return priority;
}

public String getComments() {
    return comments;
}

public void setComments(String comments) {
    this.comments = comments;
}

public String getCannedReply() {
    return cannedReply;
}

public void setCannedReply(String cannedReply) {
    this.cannedReply = cannedReply;
}

public String getStatus() {return status;}

public String getComplaintID() {
    return complaintID;
}

public static ArrayList<Ticket> getTicket()
{
    ArrayList<Ticket> tickets = new ArrayList<Ticket>();
    return tickets;
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make your ticket class as serializable and pass it in bundel and parse in other activity like bellow
First change your Ticket class definition like bellow

```
public class Ticket implements Serializable {
```

Then after change your click code like bellow

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ComplaintDetail.class);
                intent.putExtra("ticket", ticket);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

And finally parse and get your object in second activity like bellow

```
Ticket ticket= (Ticket) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("ticket");
```

Comment: Its not working. It giving a nullPointerException: Attempt to read from field Ticket.ticketCategory on a null object reference. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
   listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ComplaintDetail.class);
                intent.putExtra("ticket", ticket);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
    });
```

The object i mentioned ticket in intent is the object u receive from fireabse and you need make a object parceable to be able to send it to another activity.So, make sure sure to make it parceable.
The below is the model class with implementing parceable interface:-

```
public class Ticket implements Parcelable {
    private String ticketCategory;
    private String name;
    private String complaintID;
    private String subcategory;
    private String priority;
    private String status;
    private String comments;
    private String cannedReply;

    public Ticket() {
    }


    public Ticket(String ticketCategory, String subcategory, String priority, String status, String comments, String cannedReply) {
        this.ticketCategory = ticketCategory;
        //   this.Name = Name;
        this.subcategory = subcategory;
        this.priority = priority;
        this.status = status;
        this.comments = comments;
        this.cannedReply = cannedReply;
    }

    public String getTicketCategory() {
        return ticketCategory;
    }

    public void setTicketCategory(String ticketCategory) {
        this.ticketCategory = ticketCategory;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getComplaintID() {
        return complaintID;
    }

    public void setComplaintID(String complaintID) {
        this.complaintID = complaintID;
    }

    public String getSubcategory() {
        return subcategory;
    }

    public void setSubcategory(String subcategory) {
        this.subcategory = subcategory;
    }

    public String getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    public void setPriority(String priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public void setComments(String comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    public String getCannedReply() {
        return cannedReply;
    }

    public void setCannedReply(String cannedReply) {
        this.cannedReply = cannedReply;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(this.ticketCategory);
        dest.writeString(this.name);
        dest.writeString(this.complaintID);
        dest.writeString(this.subcategory);
        dest.writeString(this.priority);
        dest.writeString(this.status);
        dest.writeString(this.comments);
        dest.writeString(this.cannedReply);
    }

    protected Ticket(Parcel in) {
        this.ticketCategory = in.readString();
        this.name = in.readString();
        this.complaintID = in.readString();
        this.subcategory = in.readString();
        this.priority = in.readString();
        this.status = in.readString();
        this.comments = in.readString();
        this.cannedReply = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Ticket> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Ticket>() {
        @Override
        public Ticket createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Ticket(source);
        }

        @Override
        public Ticket[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Ticket[size];
        }
    };
}
```

So,I have the set and get methods and implemented the parceable i.e made the class parceable so that u can send the entire object.Now in other activity where you will be receiving,You can just use get methods like below

First get the intent through getIntent() in onCreate and declare the object Ticket.

```
 ticket = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("Ticket");
```

And where you need the object there you can directly access it like below

```
ticket.getSubcategory();
    ticket.getTicketCategory();
    ticket.getStatus();
```

So,Thats it ask me if you didn't get any thing and if it is not working.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I am not able to make it parceable as I'm not aware how to do i guess... I'm pretty new to android. I have posted the model class as well.

Comment: I Have edited and added the ans with model class implementing parceable interface.Check it out.

Comment: Its still not working. It giving a nullPointerException: Attempt to read from field Ticket.ticketCategory on a null object reference.

Comment: yeah first you need to assign the data to object and then send it.If u don't then you are sending empty object and if call get method on empty it will give you the nullPointerException .So,First the assign the data to object when you receive it from firebase.Tell me if you are still not able to do it.